# Add labels to plot for specific values in R

Tags: r, plot, label

I create a plot with the following dataset and I would like to add a label only for points flagged with a T in the "DisplayName" column.

```
Probe   Name    DisplayName X   Y
bob1    A   0   53.989643   7935.185
bob2    B   T   55.11423    7930.626
bob3    C   0   49.537724   6901.7715
bob4    D   0   57.280113   6687.0156
bob5    E   T   7.5517325   840.3756
bob6    F   0   62.68943    6666.6665
bob7    G   T   32.553364   3036.508
bob8    H   0   34.120102   2553.5354
bob9    I   0   127.54777   7818.89
```

My idea would be to use text() and which() to add the value of "Name" but I am stuck with something like this:

```
plot(data$X, data$Y)
text(data$X, data$Y, d$Name[which(d$DisplayName =="T",  arr.ind=TRUE)])
```

Any help will be appreciated,

Cheers ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can combine `subset()` and `with()` to use only part of data frame for function `text()`.

```
plot(df$X, df$Y)
with(subset(df,DisplayName=="T"),text(X,Y,Name))
```

Comment: Is it possible that this doesn't work in R 4.0?

Comment: @BrianWiley Works as expected for me with R 4.0.5.

Comment: yes thanks i just messed up with the data type be a character

Answer (score 3):

You can do this most simply (but perhaps not as elegantly as Didzis' answer) as follows:

```
plot(data$X, data$Y)
text(data$X[d$DisplayName =="T"], data$Y[d$DisplayName =="T"], d$Name[d$DisplayName =="T"])
```