# How to label values beyond threshold in plot type 'h'

Tags: r, plot, label, histogram

Using the `mtcars` dataset and `plot` function with argument  `type= 'h'`, I would like to label observations with  `mtcars$wt >4` only, but did not manage. I tried:

```
 plot(mtcars$wt,type = 'h',ylim = c(0,6))
    abline(h=4)
    text(mtcars$wt,row.names(mtcars[mtcars$wt >4,]),pos =3,col='blue',cex=0.6))
```

But all bars get labelled:

[image]

I also tried the solution provided at [Add labels to plot for specific values in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17174090/add-labels-to-plot-for-specific-values-in-r) , but did not manage to make it work.

It would be great if the labels could also be on top of the bar with a 45 degree angle to avoid overlapping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `text` function arguments have a specific order (type `?text` into the console), and when you don't use argument names the function fills the arguments in the order you've given. It seems you forgot to define `y=` or so.

Try this:

```
plot(mtcars$wt, type='h', ylim=c(0,6))
abline(h=4)
## here your old call with argument names
# text(x=mtcars$wt, y=row.names(mtcars[mtcars$wt >4,]), pos =3, col='blue', cex=0.6)
text(x=which(mtcars$wt > 4), y=mtcars$wt[mtcars$wt > 4], 
     labels=row.names(mtcars[mtcars$wt > 4,]), pos=3, col='blue', cex=0.6)
```

[image]

However, the labels are a bit lumped together. Here we could use `Map` that applies each argument one by one to the `text` function, and where we are able to add an adjustment vector to `x` and `y` arguments.

```
plot(mtcars$wt,type='h',ylim=c(0,6))
abline(h=4)
Map(function(x, y, labels) text(x, y, labels, pos=3, col="blue", cex=.6),
    x=which(mtcars$wt > 4) + c(0, -2.8, 0, 2.2),
    y=mtcars$wt[mtcars$wt > 4] + c(0, -.1, .1, -.1),
    labels=row.names(mtcars[mtcars$wt > 4,])
)
```

[image]

When we have more labels this might still look confusing to readers. Then we could use `arrows` which positions are defined in startpoints `x0, y0` and endpoints `x1, y1` and where we use the values we already have.

```
plot(mtcars$wt,type='h',ylim=c(0,8))
abline(h=4)
xpos. <- which(mtcars$wt > 4)
ypos. <- mtcars$wt[mtcars$wt > 4]
Map(function(x, y, labels) text(x, y, labels, pos=3, col="blue", cex=.6),
    x=xpos. + c(0, -6, 0, 6), y=ypos. + c(0, 1, 2, 1), 
    labels=row.names(mtcars[mtcars$wt > 4,])
)
arrows(x0=xpos. + c(0, -6, 0, 6), y0=ypos.+ c(0, 1, 2, 1), x1=xpos., y1=ypos.+.2,
       code=0, col="blue")
```

[image]

To rotate the labels, we can use `srt=` option, e.g. `srt=45` for 45°.

```
plot(mtcars$wt,type='h',ylim=c(0,8))
abline(h=4)
text(x=which(mtcars$wt > 4), y=mtcars$wt[mtcars$wt > 4], 
     labels=row.names(mtcars[mtcars$wt > 4,]), pos=3, col='blue', cex=0.6, srt=45)
```

**Note:** Better use another device than the preview window, such as `png()` or `pdf()`, because otherwise everything shifts annoyingly all the time. See answers to this question on how to do this:

- [How to save a plot as image on the disk?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7144203/6574038)

Now, have fun with tinkering! :)

Comment: Works great thank you @jay.sf, but in the event there are more nearby observations to be labelled perhaps the `map` function might not hold, so I thought having labels on a 45 degree angle, if possible, would be the ideal solution while still using `plot()` .

Comment: Very welcome @ForEverNewbie Please see my updated answer for your follow-up questions.

Answer (score 1):

There may be several ways to fix this. I tried this:

```
plot(mtcars$wt,type = 'h',ylim = c(0,6))
abline(h=4)
labs <- ifelse(mtcars$wt >4, row.names(mtcars), "")
text(mtcars$wt,labs,pos =3,col='blue',cex=0.6)
```

For the second part of your question, I would have to use `ggplot` and `ggrepel`, it may not be exactly what you after, but it can avoid overlapping:

```
library(ggrepel)
library(tidyverse)
mtcars$x = 1:length(mtcars$wt)
mtcars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x= x, xend =x, y = 0, yend= wt))+
  geom_segment() +
  geom_text_repel(aes(x= x, y = wt, label = labs), 
                      angle = 45
)
```

[image]

Comment: great thank you! Do you know how to have the labels on a 45 degree angle to avoid overlapping?

Comment: I did not see your second part of the question. Will get back to you soon

Comment: Thanks a lot @Zhiqiang Wang, I accept jay.sf´s answer though since it sticks to plot() and provides an alternative to avoid overlapping

Comment: I agree with you. Cheers